# Converting VB6 PropertyBag in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, propertybag

For certain file operations we use VB6's PropertyBag object to convert various items to a bytearray via the Content property. We then save the bytearray as part of a binary file. Later when we load the file we read back the file, read in the bytearray and reconstitute the item by using the propertybag's readproperty. We use this a lot to store images like the customer logo.

What support does .NET framework have for working with PropertyBags? Othan than writing a COM helper DLL. Are Property Bags a VB6 only construct or they are part of the general OLE/COM automation framework?

What I am hoping for is avoiding writing a VB6 helper DLL and accessing directly (via declares) the needed COM functions. I am not looking to replicate the functionality but rather converting the object stored in the bytearray into their .NET equivalent.

**NOTE:** I am not interested in implementing the functionality of a property bag in .NET. Only in being able to read the bytes of a saved VB6 Property Bag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out Edanmo's **Load and save pictures to byte arrays** sample on his [old VB6 sample page](http://www.mvps.org/emorcillo/en/code/vb6/index.shtml). It's very simple and can be used to "serialize" any object that implements IPersistStream interface like ADODB.Recordset for example. VB6's PropertyBag is using IPersistStream for objects and probably implements "custom" VT_Xxx variant-types serialization.

Btw, Edanmo's code snippet allows you to read images stored via copy/paste to an image column of an Access grid.

Answer (score 3):

There is 0 support for PropertyBags in .NET. Serailisation of objects replaces the PropertyBag construct.

So as I see it you have 2 choices.

1. Byte the bullet and write the 10 or 20 line Interop dll.
2. Analyse the contents of the serialised property bag and see if you can decode it and figure out the offsets of the images and streams etc.

I know which one I'd be heading for.

Comment: I was hoping property bags was do with something deep in the OLE engine. But it looks like interop is the way to go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is worth pointing out that you can directly access the VB6 PropertyBag from .NET by referencing the VB6 runtime DLL in your project.

Add a reference to:  `C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\MSVBVM60.DLL`  (or might by in System32 folder)

and you will then see PropertyBag in the object browser:

[image]

Note that this VB6 class does not have functionality for reading/writing to disk files, byte arrays, etc. It only manages the in-memory data (AFAIK). So this alone does not solve the issue of how to save/load data in whatever format the PropertyBag was stored in.

Comment: This is a bad idea in a long run. As VB6 ages, it is less likely to survive into newer systems, hence by depending on ` C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\MSVBVM60.DLL`, you make your .NET or any other code dependent on the soon-to-be legacy library

Comment: @tabdiukov I agree in principle, but sometimes people just have to pick the overall least-worst option, including ones which are expedient. Also the VB6 runtime has been fully supported for the lifetime of every Windows version made since VB6 was created, including the latest, so its not about to disappear. And if your program already has some legacy VB6 dependencies or entanglements, doing so it not really making the problem any worse.

Comment: Also, the only other real answer here involves an interop (which is what referencing MSVBVM60.DLL will get you).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried adding a reference to the C:\WINDOWS\SysWow64\MSVBVM60.DLL that was suggested, and I didn't get anyPropertyBag in the object browser. Maybe I did something wrong, but I wanted to parse property bag binary data.

I have analyzed the structure of the property bag, and I have a partial implementation. There are few things I don't know what they represent (I thought that maybe it's checksum of some kind, but it doesn't look like it).

Here is my implementation for reading a VB6 property bag:

```
public class PropertyBag
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _values;

    public PropertyBag(byte[] data)
    {
        _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        if (data != null && data.Length > 12
            && data[0] == 147 && data[1] == 178)
        {
            int offset = 4;
            int totalSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset);

            if (data.Length != totalSize)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("The PropertyBag total size does not match the actual data size");

            offset += 4;

            while (data.Length > offset + 4)
            {
                PropertyBagValueType valueType = (PropertyBagValueType)BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);
                offset += 2;

                var valueNameLen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, offset);
                offset += 2;
                string valueName;

                offset += 8; // Some data I don't understand

                valueName = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(data, offset, valueNameLen * 2);
                offset += valueNameLen * 2; // Unicode take 2 bytes per char
                int valueLen = 0;

                switch (valueType)
                {
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Bool:
                        valueLen = 2;
                        if (data[offset] == 0)
                            _values.Add(valueName, false);
                        else
                        {
                            Debug.Assert(data[offset] == 255);
                            _values.Add(valueName, true);
                        }
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Byte:
                        valueLen = 2;
                        _values.Add(valueName, data[offset]);
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Int16:
                        valueLen = 2;
                        _values.Add(valueName, BitConverter.ToInt16(data, offset));
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Int32:
                        valueLen = 4;
                        _values.Add(valueName, BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset));
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Single:
                        valueLen = 4;
                        _values.Add(valueName, BitConverter.ToSingle(data, offset));
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Double:
                        valueLen = 8;
                        _values.Add(valueName, BitConverter.ToDouble(data, offset));
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Currency:
                        valueLen = 8;
                        var i64Value = BitConverter.ToInt64(data, offset);
                        _values.Add(valueName, i64Value / 10000.0);
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.String:
                        valueLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset) * 2; // Unicode
                        offset += 4;
                        _values.Add(valueName, UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(data, offset, valueLen));
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.ByteArray:
                        offset += 2; // The value in the current offset seem to be 1. It might be the size per item in the array. Other array types are not seem to be supported
                        valueLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, offset);
                        offset += 4;
                        offset += 4; // I have no idea why extra 4 bytes padding. Maybe it's for supporting arrays with size larger than 4GB, but VB is 32 bit, so it can't support more than 4GB in RAM
                        _values.Add(valueName, data.Skip(offset).Take(valueLen).ToArray());
                        break;
                    case PropertyBagValueType.Date:
                        valueLen  = 8;
                        /* A Date is stored as an IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating point number, just like a Double
                        Digits to the left of the decimal point (when converted to decimal) are interperated as a date between 1 January 100 and 31 December 9999. Values to the right of the decimal point indicate time between 0:00:00 and 23:59:59.
                        The date section of the Date data type (before the decimal point), is a count of the number of days that have passed since 1 Jan 100, offset by 657434. That is, 1 Jan 100 is denoted by a value of -657434; 2 Jan 100 is denoted -657433; 31 Dec 1899 is 1; 1 Jan 2000 is 36526, and so on.
                        The time section of the date (after the decimal point) is the fraction of a day, expressed as a time. For example, 1.5 indicates the date 31 Dec 1899 (as above) and half a day, i.e. 12:00:00. So, an hour is denoted by an additional 4.16666666666667E-02, a minute by 6.94444444444444E-04, and a second by 1.15740740740741E-05.

                        Taken from: https://www.codeguru.com/visual-basic/how-visual-basic-6-stores-data/
                        */
                        var num = BitConverter.ToDouble(data, offset);
                        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
                        var days = Math.Floor(num);
                        var seconds = (num - days) * (3600 * 24);

                        dateTime = dateTime.AddDays(days);
                        dateTime = dateTime.AddSeconds(seconds);
                        _values.Add(valueName, dateTime);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported value type");
                }

                offset += valueLen;

                if (offset % 4 != 0)
                    offset += 4 - offset % 4;
            }

        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return _values.Keys.ToList();
        }
    }

    public object ReadValue(string key, object defaultValue = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        var keyToUse = key.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (_values.ContainsKey(keyToUse))
            return _values[keyToUse];

        return defaultValue;
    }
}

internal enum PropertyBagValueType
{
    Bool = 11,
    Byte = 17, // 0x11
    Int16 = 2,
    Int32 = 3,
    Single = 4,
    Double = 5,
    Currency = 6,
    String = 8,
    Date = 7,
    ByteArray = 8209, //0x2011
}
```

As you can see, I'm able to read the values of most types, including Date and Time.
I'm not sure if the value types 1, 9, 10, 12-16 are occupied.
I was assuming that 1 will be used for bit/boolean, but it's not, and the enumeration of Byte is higher than Int16 and Int32

Since PropertyBag doesn't support inner property bags, classes, and collections, then I'm not sure what other types I have not covered.

Someone has anything else to add? (like types I've missed out?)