# Equivalent UserControl events?

Tags: c#, vb6, user-controls, vb6-migration

I had some UserControls in VB6. I want to convert to C#.  What are the equivalent events in C#?

```
Private Sub UserControl_Initialize()
'...
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()
'...
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
'...
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
'...
End Sub
```

Comment: See this [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12282/Implementing-a-PropertyBag-in-C). also look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569707/converting-vb6-propertybag-in-net) it deals with vb.net but should still be applicable

Comment: Thanks. I am new babie in C#.

Comment: In Windows Forms, component properties are normally populated via the parent's InitializeComponent() method.